Magento 2.4.6 src/pub/static is empty CSS Not Loading after GULP LIVE
I've setup a Docker for a Magento 2.4.6 staging site locally and after compiling the CSS styles aren't loading.
I can see them in the browser source but the src/pub/static is empty!
I ran GULP LIVE and everything seems fine apart from the styles.
Anyone have any ideas?
